# Getting error: Cannot read properties of undefined in javascript

Tags: javascript, datamodel

While calling function getting error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'username')
    at getLoginData (<anonymous>:3:30)
    at <anonymous>:1:1"
```

`role1` has value "administrator", but why it is not able to call in `datamodel`? (Datamodel here refers is another JSON file)

```
datamodel = {
  administrator: [
    {
      username: "abc@xyz.com",
      password: "abc@1234",
    },
    {
      username: "abcd@xyz.com",
      password: "xyz@1234",
    },
  ],
};

function getLoginData(role1) {
  console.log(role1);
  let name = datamodel.role1.username;
}

getLoginData("administrator[0]");
```

Comment: You can't access the object in that manner. You can pass `administratror` as a string to the  object to access using bracket notation (eg. `datamodel[role1][0].username`) but you cannot include the index accessor in that string.

Answer (score 3):

You can't access object in that was, the code thinks that role1 is a key in that Object.

```
function getLoginData(role1){
        console.log(role1)
       let name=datamodel[role1][0].username
 }
    
getLoginData("administrator")
```

Comment: Better to pass role and desired array index as parameters.

Comment: function getLoginData(role1,index){

       let name=datamodel[role1][index].username
 }
    
getLoginData("administrator")


I can use this right?because I have many test cases and  to use index and roles dynamically

Comment: yess you can do that just pass the index & role u want

Comment: Yes, but you would call `getLoginData("administrator", 0)`

Answer (score 0):

```
var datamodel = {
                "administrator": [
                    {
                    "username": "abc@io.com",
                    "password": "abc@1234"
                    },
                    {
                    "username": "xyz@io.com",
                    "password": "xyz@1234"
                    }
                ]
            }
            console.log(datamodel);
            var name = datamodel.administrator[0].username; //get the name of administrator[0] = "rinty.kurian@espacenetworks.io"
            console.log(name);
```

Try this :)

Comment: datmodel is another json file and I need to reuse the code in function for 3 4 cases, that's y created function

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to use [`Brackets Notation`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors#bracket_notation) to access an `object`'s attribute that is stored inside of another variable. So assuming you want the first credentials from the `administrators` array you would write something like `datamodel.administrator[0]`.

Since, as it seems from your function's call, `getLoginData('administrator[0]')`, you would like that the function `getLoginData` to take care of accessing the inner `administrators` array which we cannot directly using `brackets notation` as `datamodel['administrators[0]']` will raise an error because the attribute `"administrators[0]"` (string) doesn't exist in the `datamodel` object.

What we need to do is to try to extract the index of the items we want to return, if it exists, and then use that to return the right credentials from the `datamodel` object.

To do so, we will split the argument that is passed to `getLoginData` to get the attribute we want to access (ex: administrators) and the index (ex: 0).

Here's a live demo to implement such functionality:

```js
const dataModel = {
    "administrator": [{
        "username": "abc@xyz.com",
        "password": "abc@1234"
      },
      {
        "username": "abcd@xyz.com",
        "password": "xyz@1234"
      }
    ]
  },
  /** 
   * a function that accepts an attribute name and optional index to get from "datamodel" object
   */
  getLoginData = role => {
    /** 
     * split the role parameter to get the wanted index if there is one
     * the trick here is that we will replace the brackets around the index with a space and only keep the index itself (we'll get rid of those brackets)
     * we should make some checks to prevent undefined index like errors
     */
    const splitted = role.replace(/\[(\d+)\]/, ' $1').split(' '),
      attr = dataModel[splitted[0]] ? (splitted.length > 1 ? dataModel[splitted[0]][splitted[1]] : dataModel[splitted[0]]) : null;
    /** return the appropriete attribute or null if not defined */
    return attr ? attr.username : null;
  };
// prints: "abc@xyz.com"
console.log(getLoginData("administrator[0]"))
```

### UPDATE

Here's another possible solution that works by passing the item index as the second parameter to `datamodel` object.

```js
const dataModel = {
    "administrator": [{
        "username": "abc@xyz.com",
        "password": "abc@1234"
      },
      {
        "username": "abcd@xyz.com",
        "password": "xyz@1234"
      }
    ]
  },
  /** 
   * a function that accepts an attribute name and an index to get from "datamodel" object
   */
  getLoginData = (role, index) => dataModel[role] && dataModel[role][index] ? dataModel[role][index].username : null;
// prints: "abc@xyz.com"
console.log(getLoginData("administrator", 0))
```